# Cannot suspend after using VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, suspend

I have noticed that after I have used VirtualBox, I cannot suspend my computer. It enters a suspend state, but after a couple of seconds it wakes up again. Only a reboot has been able to solve the problem. I tried killing all processes related to VirtualBox (so that `pgrep VBox` shows nothing), and also removing the corresponding kernel module (`rmmod vboxdrv` etc), but the problem did not go away.

I'm using VirtualBox 5.2.12 r122591 installed from [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and Kubuntu 16.04.

Edit:
I have my virtual HDD on an external USB drive, and after more troubleshooting I just noticed that it is only if after running VBox I disconnect the USB drive that the problem appears. If I reconnect the drive, I can suspend again.

Here is what dmesg says around the time I tried but failed to suspend, without the external USB disk plugged in. Perhaps that "usb4-port2: cannot disable (err = -32)" is a hint? Indeed, with the drive plugged in and suspending successfully, that error message is not present.

```
[ 5494.368977] wlp3s0: associated
[ 5494.369023] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 5754.738860] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
[ 5754.738875] usb usb4-port2: cannot disable (err = -32)
[ 5754.738884] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 5756.953098] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 00:a3:8e:2f:c7:0f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 5756.964940] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5756.964944] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 5756.964945] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 5756.964956] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5756.964958] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5756.964960] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5756.964962] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5756.964965] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 5756.964967] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 5756.964968] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5756.964969] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 5767.017337] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 5767.518420] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 5768.126947] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 5768.129146] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 5768.130421] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 5768.130439] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 5768.130710] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 5768.130734] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 5768.132184] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 5768.145600] serial 00:07: disabled
[ 5768.145604] serial 00:07: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5768.146256] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[ 5768.146710] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 5768.671168] PM: suspend of devices complete after 540.567 msecs
[ 5768.687093] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.917 msecs
[ 5768.688913] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5768.689329] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5768.689919] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5768.689933] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 5768.704904] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 17.805 msecs
[ 5768.705573] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 5768.727262] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 5768.727263] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 5768.727271] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 5768.727762] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.728799] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 5768.740154] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.740161] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.741201] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 5768.752172] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.752177] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.753216] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 5768.764200] Broke affinity for irq 19
[ 5768.764217] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 5768.764222] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.764226] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.765260] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 5768.776119] Broke affinity for irq 19
[ 5768.776133] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 5768.776136] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.776139] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.777163] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 5768.788073] Broke affinity for irq 19
[ 5768.788086] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 5768.788089] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 5768.788092] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.788096] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.789118] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 5768.799918] Broke affinity for irq 1
[ 5768.799922] Broke affinity for irq 8
[ 5768.799925] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 5768.799929] Broke affinity for irq 12
[ 5768.799933] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 5768.799936] Broke affinity for irq 19
[ 5768.799939] Broke affinity for irq 21
[ 5768.799943] Broke affinity for irq 23
[ 5768.799946] Broke affinity for irq 27
[ 5768.799949] Broke affinity for irq 28
[ 5768.799953] Broke affinity for irq 30
[ 5768.799956] Broke affinity for irq 32
[ 5768.799959] Broke affinity for irq 34
[ 5768.800985] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 5768.817067] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 5768.817118] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 5768.817118] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 5768.818067] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x20, date = 2018-04-10
[ 5768.818106] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 5768.837049] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 5768.837050] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 5768.837767] microcode: CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x20, date = 2018-04-10
[ 5768.840330]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.840417] CPU1 is up
[ 5768.861080] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 5768.861795] microcode: CPU2 microcode updated early to revision 0x20, date = 2018-04-10
[ 5768.864368]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.864453] CPU2 is up
[ 5768.885123] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 5768.885837] microcode: CPU3 microcode updated early to revision 0x20, date = 2018-04-10
[ 5768.888434]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.888518] CPU3 is up
[ 5768.909171] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[ 5768.912152]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.912217] CPU4 is up
[ 5768.929096] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[ 5768.931966]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.932027] CPU5 is up
[ 5768.957122] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[ 5768.960016]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.960077] CPU6 is up
[ 5768.981169] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[ 5768.984186]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
[ 5768.984249] CPU7 is up
[ 5768.991398] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 5769.357834] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5769.358162] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5769.358885] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5769.358981] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 17.714 msecs
[ 5769.359509] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.496 msecs
[ 5769.360884] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 5769.360887] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[ 5769.426192] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 3 resume PLC timeout
[ 5769.508517] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5769.522629] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 5769.532733] serial 00:07: activated
[ 5769.577344] usb 4-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 5769.588916] usb 1-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 5769.592968] usb 2-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 5769.688940] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 5769.704943] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 5769.705200] usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 5769.708953] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 5769.710212] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

Comment: Can you try it then check `dmesg` to see what it's saying?

Comment: Now that we have systemd probably better: `journalctl -xe -p err -k`, paste relevant lines